# Splitting a long string by last space, but no longer substrings then 132 characters

Tags: java, string, substring, split

What I need to achieve is:

- I have a string that can be from 0 chars up to 300 chars from a input.
- I need to split the string into an array with max 132 chars per line.
- I need to split the string on the last space counting backwards from 132.
- The next line shouldn't start with a space.
- If the string is under 132 chars it should send the entire/remaining of the string.

I've tried different Java codes that I've found on Google and that I've have modified to suit my needs. Got different result, but they always seems to be offset the further I get down the array.

```
public void SplitString(String[] input, ResultList result, Container container) throws     StreamTransformationException{

int i = 0;
int start = 0;
int end = 0;

//loop through entire values in input array
for (int j=0; j<input.length; j++) { 
  if (input[j].length() == 0) {

       result.addValue("");

  }
else {
            //repeat for the length of each value
      for (i=0;i<input[j].length(); i=i+(input[j].lastIndexOf(" ",132))) {
           start =i;
           end =i+input[j].lastIndexOf(" ",132);

               if (input[j].length()> end) {
                   result.addValue(input[j].substring(start,end));
           }

           if (!(input[j].length()==0)){
                if (end >= input[j].length()) { 
                     end = end -input[j].lastIndexOf(" ",132);
                     result.addValue( input[j].substring(end,input[j].length()));
                }

           }      
         }
  }     
}
```

Been edeting my code back and forth, but this is the "last edition". I know this code doesn't consider if the string is initial shorter then 132 chars, and thus breaks the string into two lines in the array. I've removed this in the code to try to tackle the other problem in the array first.

Comment: So please show your code...

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add the code :(

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem and tried it like this:

```
public void splitString(String input, List result) {
```

`String[] words = input.split(" ");

System.out.println(words.length);

String currentLine = "";
for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    String word = words[i];
    if ((currentLine.length() + word.length()) < 132) {
        currentLine += " " + word;
    } else {
        result.add(currentLine);
        currentLine = word;
    }
}

result.add(currentLine);`

}

It works, but this way requires, that your input string contains whitespaces.
So feel free to improve it...